# Script output formatting

Tags: bash, shell

I am having a script output data that needs to be formatted, I have a output like below.

```
UNIT : ABC
xxxx
xxxx
Free memory : xxx 70

UNIT : DEF
xxxx
xxxx
Free memory : xxx 60
```

I need to capture free memory data for individual units but I am unable to print that out, any suggestions ? There are some 25 units & I have to print free memories of all of them individually.

Here "xxxxx" is some random data which is irrelevant for me, what I want is to print free memory for each unit, something like below format :slight_smile

```
ABC 70
DEF 60
```

and so on.

Comment: Can you show your script? And can it be changed or this has to be done after the script execution?

Comment: So what have you tried? This should be trivial with `awk`.

Comment: It would be easier to extract this from whatever data the script is formatting, or at least have the script provide a more machine-parseable output format as an option.

Comment: This has to be done after script execution, the problem here is UNIT & FREE MEMORY for that unit are not in same line so formatting is bit difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Let the file `output.txt` contains the output,

Then Assuming, the order of **UNIT and Free memory** doesn't change in the output, we could try the following.

```
cat output.txt | grep -Ea 'UNIT|Free memory' | sed -e ':a;N;s/\nFree/ Free/g' | awk '{print $3" "$8}'
```

**Output:**

```
ABC 70
DEF 60
```

**Explanation:**

- `grep -Ea 'UNIT|Free memory'` : This will grep out only the lines contains either **UNIT** or **Free memory**.
- `sed -e ':a;N;s/\nFree/ Free/g'` : This will loop through each line, and wherever new line starts with **Free**, the new line will replace with a space. Hence we will get **UNIT** and **Free memory** in a single line.
- `awk '{print $3" "$8}'` : This further cut out the positions of **UNIT name** and **Free memory value**.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `sed`

```
/path/to/your/script |
sed -n -E '/^UNIT\s*:\s*/{s///;h}; /^Free memory\s*:.*\s([0-9]+)$/{s//\1/;H;g;s/\n/ /p}'
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `ed`

If it is a file.

```sh
ed -s file.txt < script.ed
```

If the output is coming from a script, requires a shell that supports `<()` Process Substitution.

```sh
ed -s <(cat file.txt) < script.ed
```

- Replace the `cat` part with the output/command from your script.

The `script.ed` script.

```sh
v/^UNIT\|^Free/d
,s/.*[[:space:]]\(.*\)$/\1/g
,s/$/ /
g/./j
,s/ $//
,p
Q
```

Answer (score 0):

Just send your script's output into this awk command:

```
Your_Script | awk '
/^UNIT/ {printf $NF" "}
/^Free memory/ {print $NF}
'
```